# xcdebuild ios14 with googleMap framework build

Tags: xcodebuild, ios14, xcode12

Since ios14 update I am not able to build my application on my CI machine. It works in Xcode (I have build and released my app to test flight). But I cannot get it to compile and unit test via xcodebuild cli

here is the command I write to launch my unit tests.

```
xcodebuild -workspace ./ios-apps.xcworkspace -scheme SCHEMENAME -sdk iphonesimulator14.0 -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11,OS=14.0' test CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```

I tried with option but it ended with the same error EXCLUDE_ARCH=arm64

Here is the error:

Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file 'PATHTOPROJECT/Carthage/Build/iOS/GoogleMapsCore.framework/GoogleMapsCore' for architecture arm64.

Is there anything I can do to make it work or do I need to file a report to google maps team ?
I tried to update my carthage dep and relink them but it did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few research I understand more the error.
It seems that Apple is preparing for future arm64 mac and coming with them arm64 simulator.

As google maps framework binaries does obviously not include this build arch for the moment it seems that using the option ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES is the solution to my problem

My working command is now

```
xcodebuild -workspace ./ios-apps.xcworkspace -scheme SCHEMENAME -sdk iphonesimulator14.0 -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11,OS=14.0' test CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES
```